# Use model instance in custom templatetag

Tags: django

How can i get current instance model in templatetag, like:

templatetags/description_tag.py

```
from django import template
from users.models import Product

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name='description_tag')
def description_tag():
    custom_description = Product.product_description
    return custom_description
```

with this a get the object : `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute`

I have no ideia to get a current instance model, any tip?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass object (or id and get object) before you try to get the field value.

```
@register.simple_tag(name='description_tag')
def description_tag(product):
    custom_description = product.product_description
    return custom_description

# or if you have only id of Product object
@register.simple_tag(name='description_tag')
def description_tag(id):
    custom_description = Product.objects.get(id=id).product_description
    return custom_description
```

and in template something like:

```
{% product|description_tag %}

# or
{% some_id|description_tag %}
```

But to be more precise you need to share your model.